# Prove the exterior derivative is a linear transformation of vector spaces.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, exterior-derivative

Let $\omega_1$ be a $k$-form and $\omega_2$ be an $l$-form, both defined in an open subset $U\subset \mathbf R^3$. Let $d:\wedge^k(U)\rightarrow\wedge^{k+1}(U)$ be the exterior derivative of differential forms. Show that $d$ is a linear transformation of vector spaces.

I have the formula:
$$ d\omega=\sum df_{i_1...i_n}\wedge dx_{i_1}\wedge...\wedge dx_{i_n} $$

It's my understanding that to do this I need to show 
$$ d(\omega_1+\omega_2)=d(\omega_1)+d(\omega_2) $$
and 
$$ d(k\omega_1)=k*d(\omega_1) $$ 
But the first property is false right below is a given property of the exterior derivative: 
$$ d(\omega_1+\omega_2)=d(\omega_1)\wedge\omega_2+(-1)^k\omega_1\wedge d(\omega_2) $$

Comment: The left hand side of the last equation should be $d(\omega_1\land\omega_2)$, so it doesn't contradict linearity.

Comment: ohhh okay yeah I had that wrong and it was causing so much confusion

Comment: Are those the only two properties I need to show it is a linear transformation

Comment: Yes. But differentiation is a linear operator.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how to represent $\omega_1+\omega_2$

Comment: Simply add them..